# Is there any possible way to set select dropdown list that no matter what will always open towards the bottom of the browser

Tags: html, css

I have this page which display a certain select element at around the middle of the page, and everytime the select element is opened, it always opened towards the top of the browser, I know that this is because the space between the select element to the top of the browser is wider than the space between the select element to the bottom of the browser, however I would still like to set the select element to ALWAYS open towards the bottom of the browser. I have googled and search here, but nothing comes up.

Please, if anyone knows a method to do this. Thank you.

Comment: In short: NO you cannot do this unless you create fake (self-made) drop down lists. Then it's just block elements and css and nobody needs to tell you how to fix that.

Select boxes are in most cases barely stylable or controlable by css so layers with other elements are being used instead with javascript and css.

Comment: Regarding MathijsSegers' remark, it's important to note about the proposed solution that it usually needs a lot of coding to reflect the usability features of form controls (e.g.: focus when label is clicked, tabindex, keyboard navigation,...)

Comment: I thought I'd push my .js skills to the limit and see if I could put together my own (self-made) drop down list. I have posted it as an answer below. It can certainly be improved with regard to accessibility, but (maintaining modesty) I think it's a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an over-elaborate solution, but worth a shot.

**A  list which *always* drops down:**

https://jsfiddle.net/840ybhgw/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li>Select from dropdown...</li>
<li>Option 1</li>
<li>Option 2</li>
<li>Option 3</li>
<li>Option 4</li>
<li>Option 5</li>
<li>Option 6</li>
<li>Option 7</li>
<li>Option 8</li>
<li>Option 9</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
.dropdown {
width: 190px;
border:1px solid rgba(127,127,127,1);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.dropdown li {
height: 18px;
padding: 1px 2px;
}

.dropdown li,.dropdown.minimised:hover li {
display: none;
}

.dropdown li:nth-of-type(1) {
font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown li:nth-of-type(1)::after {
content: "\25bc";
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -1px;
right: -2px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: rgba(63,63,255,1);
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
text-align:center;
font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown li:nth-of-type(1),.dropdown:hover li {
display: block;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
background-color: rgba(0,154,253,1);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
var dropDownOptions = [];

function selectFromDropdown(i) {
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
var option = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('li')[i];
var selectedOption = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
selectedOption.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;

var selectedValue = option.innerHTML;
selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/\s/g,'');
selectedValue = selectedValue.toLowerCase();

var dropdownValue = document.createAttribute('value');
dropdownValue.value = selectedValue;
dropdown.setAttributeNode(dropdownValue);

dropdown.classList.toggle('minimised');
dropdown.onmouseout = function() {
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
if (dropdown.classList.contains('minimised') === true) {
dropdown.classList.toggle('minimised');
}
}
}

function initialiseDropdownOptionFunction(i) {
        return function(){
                var option = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[i];
                option.addEventListener('click',function(){selectFromDropdown(i);},false);};}

function initialiseDropdownOptions() {
        var options = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                initialiseDropdownOptions[i] = initialiseDropdownOptionFunction(i);
                initialiseDropdownOptions[i]();}}

window.onload = initialiseDropdownOptions();
```

Comment: N.B. When you select an option from the dropdown list above, the `<ul>` acquires a `value="[VALUE]"` property. Eg. if you select _Option 9_, in the live DOM, the `<ul>` will now read as `<ul class="dropdown" value="option9">`

Comment: Nice work ! how do I get the value of the option selected using php though ? I mean what is the name of the select ? as in $_POST['name']; ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `name="[NAME]"` attribute to the `<ul>` in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

One immediate solution - depending on context, this might not be ideal for you - is to ensure the page always scrolls up by just enough when you click on the select element, so that the dropdown list *does* always open toward the bottom of the browser.

**HTML**

```
<select class="dropdown">
[...]
</select>
```

**Javascript** [... just before `</body>` ...]

```
<script>

function raiseDropdown() {
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
window.scrollTo(0,dropdown.offsetTop-400);}

function initialiseRaiseDropdown() {
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
dropdown.addEventListener('click',raiseDropdown,false}

window.onload = initialiseRaiseDropdown();

</script>
```

Comment: nice tips. I can make use of this on other pages, thx. However in this special page, I specifically design it so that the content always fit the page (no scroll up and down at all)..

Comment: Yep, I wondered if that might be the case. As far as I know the dropdown/dropup behaviour of the <select> element is controlled by the browser and cannot be overridden via Javascript or CSS.